# construct an unordered_map with value being a pair of string and object type

Tags: c++, functor, unordered-map

consider the following code:

```
namespace fruit {
    struct apple{
        ...
    };
}

namespace language{
    struct english{
        ...
    };
}
```

I want to do something like:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, ? > mymap = { 
    {"paul", {"like", fruit::apple} },
    {"jonas", {"like", language::english} }
};
```

the key of my map is a string and the value should be such a pair `<string, ? >`.
What type should I give as value for my map? I think things like union or functor can be used to solve the problem, but how? thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you want `std::variant` or `std::any`

Comment: What's the goal of the exercise? How do you envision using `mymap`, once constructed? Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Naive solution would be `std::tuple<std::string,std::unique_ptr<fruit::apple>,std::unique_ptr<language::english>>` and make either `nullptr`

Comment: Use factory pattern and register each object (fruit::apple, language::english etc). Use functor in the unordered_map. You may need proxy pattern to wrap the object before hand so that you can apply inheritance.

Comment: @seccpur  can you provide an example? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution using std::type_index.

```
typedef std::pair<std::string, std::type_index> myPair;

std::unordered_map<std::string, myPair> myMap =
{
    {"paul", {"likes", std::type_index(typeid(fruit::apple))} },
    {"jonas",  {"likes", std::type_index(typeid(language::english))} }
};
```

thanks guys for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a snippet ( without the factory pattern => improve the syntax ) with proxy pattern so that you need not modify your existing objects:

```
struct base {
};

namespace fruit {
    struct apple {};
    struct apple_proxy: base {
        apple_proxy()
            :apple_ptr(make_shared<fruit::apple>())
        {}
        shared_ptr<apple> apple_ptr;
    };
}

namespace language {
    struct english {};
    struct english_proxy : base {
        english_proxy()
        :english_ptr(make_shared<language::english>())
        {}
        shared_ptr<english> english_ptr;
    };
}

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, shared_ptr<base>> map;

    shared_ptr<fruit::apple_proxy> a = make_shared<fruit::apple_proxy>();
    map.emplace(make_pair("apple",a));

    shared_ptr<language::english_proxy> e = make_shared<language::english_proxy>();
    map.emplace(make_pair("english", e));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code compiles for me:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>
#include <variant>

namespace fruit {
   struct apple{};
}

namespace language{
   struct english{};
}

int main(){
    std::unordered_map<std::string,std::pair<std::string,std::variant<fruit::apple, language::english> > > mymap { 
        {"paul", {"like", fruit::apple()} },
        {"jonas", {"like", language::english()}}
    };
}
```

Note that you may want to compile with something like `-std=gnu++17`.

Comment: std::variant<fruit::apple, language::english>
 
-i'm limited to c++11

-There is like 30 type  as fruit::apple, language::english, .., It will be inconvenient to write them all in the map declaration.. is there another way?

Comment: Then use `boost::variant`

Comment: Can u use polymorphism? You may want to make both `fruit::apple` and `language::english` inherit from same `base` class and instead of using `std::variant` you would use the `base` class.

Comment: @Antua i can't use polymorphism. In my real case scenario, both fruit::apple and language::english have been designed years ago.. and don't inherit from any class..

Comment: Then construct your own wrapper. No other solution comes to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use `std::variant` or `boost::variant` this solution could work:

```
struct data {
    std::string action;
    std::unque_ptr<fruit::apple> apple;
    std::unque_ptr<language::english> english;

    data( std::string act, fruit::apple ap ) : 
        action( std::move( act ) ), 
        apple( std::make_unqiue<fruit::apple>( std::move( ap ) ) {}
    data( std::string act, language::english en ) : 
        action( std::move( act ) ), 
        english( std::make_unqiue<language::english>( std::move( en ) ) {}
};
```

but most probably your problem has better solution.